# Is every planar graph a possible dual graph of a voronoi diagram?

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs, voronoi-diagrams

My question is: Given a planar graph defined by its adjacency matrix. Can I always find a set of points, so that the dual graph of the voronoi diagram of that set of points is the same as the planar graph?

Answer (score 1):

No. The dual graph of a Voronoi diagram is the [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) of its point set so, in particular, every interior face of it is a triangle. But there are plenty of planar graphs (e.g., the $4$-cycle) that have non-triangular interior faces.

Comment: This is not correct. The Delaunay triangulation may not be unique and this breaks the proof. For example, the points $\{(\pm 1,\pm 1)\}$ have Voronoi regions which have the adjacency of a 4-cycle.

Comment: However, this answer is still morally correct, in the sense that I think it highlights the right question to ask. Is every triangulated plane graph a dual graph of some Voronoi diagram? I might ask this on mathoverflow if I can't figure it out.